# Extract part of a file name in bash

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell

I have a folder with lots of files having a pattern, which is some string followed by a date and time:

```
BOS_CRM_SUS_20130101_10-00-10.csv (3 strings before date)
SEL_DMD_20141224_10-00-11.csv (2 strings before date)
SEL_DMD_SOUS_20141224_10-00-10.csv (3 strings before date)
```

I want to loop through the folder and extract only the part before the date and output into a file.

```
Output
BOS_CRM_SUS_
SEL_DMD_
SEL_DMD_SOUS_
```

This is my script but it is not working

```
#!/bin/bash

# script variables
FOLDER=/app/list/l088app5304d1/socles/Data/LEMREC/infa_shared/Shell/Check_Header_T24/

LOG_FILE=/app/list/l088app5304d1/socles/Data/LEMREC/infa_shared/Shell/Check_Header_T24/log

echo "Starting the programme at:  $(date)" >> $LOG_FILE

# Getting part of the file name from FOLDER
for file in `ls $FOLDER/*.csv`
do
    mv "${file}" "${file/date +%Y%m%d HH:MM:SS}" 2>&1 | tee -a $LOG_FILE
done #> $LOG_FILE
```

Comment: `echo BOS_CRM_SUS_20130101_10-00-10.csv | sed -r 's/(.*)20[01][0-9].*/\1/'`

Comment: The pattern in `${file/pattern/replace}` is a filename globbing pattern, not a shell command.

Comment: You can go ahead and change your loop to `for file in "$FOLDER"/*.csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sed` with extended-regex and groups to achieve this.

```
cat filelist | sed -r 's/(.*)[0-9]{8}_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].csv/\1/'
```

where `filelist` is a file with all the names you care about. Of course, this is just a placeholder because I don't know how you are going to list all eligible files. If a glob will do, for example, you can do

```
ls mydir/*.csv | sed -r 's/(.*)[0-9]{8}_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].csv/\1/'
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you wont have numbers in the first part, you could use:

```
$ for i in *csv;do  str=$(echo $i|sed -r 's/[0-9]+.*//'); echo $str; done
BOS_CRM_SUS_
SEL_DMD_
SEL_DMD_SOUS_
```

Or with [parameter substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PCTPATREF):

```
$ for i in *csv;do echo ${i%_*_*}_; done
BOS_CRM_SUS_
SEL_DMD_
SEL_DMD_SOUS_
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use `${var/pattern/replace}`, the `pattern` must be a filename glob, not command to execute.

Instead of using the substitution operator, use the pattern removal operator

```
mv "${file}" "${file%_*-*-*.csv}.csv"
```

`%` finds the shortest match of the pattern at the end of the variable, so this pattern will just match the date and time part of the filename.

Answer (score 2):

The substitution:

```
"${file/date +%Y%m%d HH:MM:SS}"
```

is unlikely to do anything, because it doesn't execute `date +%Y%m%d HH:MM:SS`. It just treats it as a pattern to search for, and it's not going to be found.

If you did execute the command, though, you would get the *current* date and time, which is also (apparently) not what you find in the filename.

If that pattern is precise, then you can do the following:

```
echo "${file%????????_??-??-??.csv}" >> "$LOG_FILE"
```

Answer (score 1):

using `grep`:

```
ls *.csv | grep -Po "\K^([A-Za-z]+_)+"
```

output:

```
BOS_CRM_SUS_
SEL_DMD_
SEL_DMD_SOUS_
```